# Should I use c: or d: on azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an Azure VM and I can see two drives c: and d:(says temp storage). Both drive allow me to create projects folders and use from Visual Studio. I would like to know which drive I get billed ie which one is the reliable drive which I should be using - Any one having idea?

Thanks
PL

Answer (score 3):

In Azure VMs

`C:\` drive comes along with the VM which 127 GB, no more no less. So this is the root volume and OS is also installed here, so might 127 GB - 40 GB so roughly 70 GB free space you can use.

```
C:\ - Cost : No Additional Cost, comes with compute charges
```

`D:\` Is called the temporary drive, it is not persistent and when you stop and start the machine, this volume would be recycled. This drive operates at very high speed, this is good for temporary file storage etc. You can use this for logging as well, if you need to persist those logs, you can run a background job to push it Azure Blob or stuff etc.

> D:\ - Cost : No Additional Cost, comes with compute charges

`E:\ F:\ G:\ H:\ ...` etc all can be used for all **practical purposes**. You will essentially attach a blob.

- One suggestion what I can provide is you can attach a blank drive directly of 1TB ( for Azure 1023 GB). You will not be billed for the whole 1023 GB but only for volume of data being stored in the drive.
- This drive would relatively slower than the C:\ & D:\, for the reasons of latency. It takes relatively longer to write over the wire and then to blob, than directly to the self attached disk. But that is the **trade off which you need to choose for the size vs. speed.**

> E:\ F:\ G:\ H:\ ... - Cost : Additional Cost for storage,
>   transactions / operation

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows Azure VM any data written to C: will be persisted across shutdowns, any data written to D: will be lost if the machine is shut down (from the management portal). So you should be using C:\ to store your data. Although it is recommended to have a separate disk drive to be attached for any in VM storage like application data etc.

If you need any additional drives on which data should be persisted across shutdowns/de-allocations you can add additional data disks to the Virtual Machine. There is a cap/limit on the number of data disks, which depends on the size of the virtual machine you have created.

You get billed for VM instance and not the temp storage.